# Get text value from xml in soapui groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

My task is get value from xml in soapui to create next test in a sequence.

I use groovy script

My target is get text inside  tag. It's easy to recognize becouse it's base64 encoded string.

```
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project ;
def tcase = project.testSuites["ChangeRetentionByCopyDemoSuite"].testCases["Milestone2"] ; 
def tstep = tcase.getTestStepByName("getDocuments - GetContentURLRequest");

def responseTestSuite1 = tstep.getPropertyValue("response");

log.info(responseTestSuite1.toString());

def gutils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def holder = gutils.getXmlHolder("$responseTestSuite1");

def byteResponse = holder.getNodeValue("/S:Envelope/S:Body/g:getDocumentsResponse/text()");
```

log.info(byteResponse);

The xml responce in **getDocuments - GetContentURLRequest**

> ```
>     <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>    <S:Header>
>       <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
>          <Timestamp xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
>             <Created>2015-09-15T13:57:50.844Z</Created>
>             <Expires>2015-09-16T13:57:50.844Z</Expires>
>          </Timestamp>
>       </Security>
>    </S:Header>
>    <S:Body>
>       <getDocumentsResponse xmlns="http://asg.com/2009/03/schemas/tciadapters/getdocument">
>          <result>
>             <operationStatus>
>                <severity>INFO</severity>
>                <reasonCode>A300</reasonCode>
>                <messageText>All requests completed without errors.</messageText>
>             </operationStatus>
>             <documents>
>                <DocumentData>
>                   <docId>
>                      <NameValuePair>
>                         <keyName>cmis:objectId</keyName>
>                         <keyValue>idd_48716F01-F5F7-4702-AC80-4EC70C949121</keyValue>
>                      </NameValuePair>
>                   </docId>
>                   <status xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>                   <content>
>                      <ContentSegment>
>                         <data>aHR0cHM6Ly91c3J5ZTh0Y2k0bTAyLmFzZy5jb206NzQ0My9jbWlzYWRhcHRlci9nZXRjb250ZW50P3VzZXJpZD1kZXY2ZGV2aWQmcGFzc3dvcmQ9ZGV2ZWxvcCUyMzEmY21pc19pbnN0YW5jZT1GaWxlTmV0UDgrLStBdG9tUHViJnJlcG9zaXRvcnk9ZmlsZW5ldG9iamVjdHN0b3JlMSZjbWlzOm9iamVjdElkPWlkZF80ODcxNkYwMS1GNUY3LTQ3MDItQUM4MC00RUM3MEM5NDkxMjE=</data>
>                      </ContentSegment>
>                   </content>
>                   <metadata/>
>                   <properties>
>                      <subrange xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>                      <format xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
>                      <supportedFormats/>
>                   </properties>
>                   <retention/>
>                </DocumentData>
>             </documents>
>          </result>
>       </getDocumentsResponse>
>    </S:Body>
> </S:Envelope>
> ```

Unfortunately I got exception when run last line of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to extract text inside the tag "messageText" then, you could specify the parent node and the child node, i.e., modify your last line to

```
def byteResponse = holder.getNodeValue("//*:operationStatus//*:messageText")

// since there is only one tag named "messageText" in the entire response, you could use this also

def byteResponse = holder.getNodeValue("//*:messageText")
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. we have been using ("//*[local-name()='messageText']") for so long. The way you suggested is shorter and better