# SoapUI - Extract XML value between tags using Groovy Script

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I would like to iterate through an x amount of Test Steps and extract an XML value in Groovy

I have found something on StackOverflow that has worked and actually extracted the value. However, I was unable to implement a loop.

Here's [a link](http://webservice-testing.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/list-teststeps-using-groovy-script-in.html)! I found which was really useful; still I could not implement.

This is the script that I had found on here is :

```
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project ;
def tcase = 
project.testSuites["Testsuite_name"].testCases["TestCase Name"] ; 
def tstep = tcase.getTestStepByName("TestStep");

def responseTestSuite1 = tstep.getPropertyValue("response");

log.info(responseTestSuite1.toString());

def gutils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def holder = gutils.getXmlHolder("$responseTestSuite1");

def byteResponse = holder.getNodeValue("//*:number")
```

The Output of this is : Script-result : 023903122

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588131/get-text-value-from-xml-in-soapui-groovy-script)!

If anyone could help that would be great !

Comment: Can you show  the screen shot of your test case? You want only process a particular step as you mentioned in your script? If so, `iterate through an x amount of Test Steps` is confusing. Please clarify. Use edit question to update.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to iterate through approximately 14 TestSteps and retrieve ("//*:number")

Comment: Well, please add the requested info

Comment: Hi Rao, here is the image http://imgur.com/PhxReAM

Comment: @Rao could you please help. Thank you.

Comment: please show the response. Does all the requests have the same /similar response ? And what do you need to do with the extracted data? Need to used it further? or just log the details and ignore?

Comment: All the responses are the same with the same XML Node. Ideally, I would like to extract it to a txt file; would like the format to be:
Name : [NameofResponse]
Value : [XMLNodeValue]

Comment: Can you show the response xml please? you may need not to show with original data, putting dummy data, but with the same structure.

Comment: Thank you so much Rao and daggett. I have now solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case the variable `tcase` references to [TestCase](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestCase.html) object.

and you can use `tcase.getTestStepCount()` to get steps count and `tcase.getTestStepAt(int index)` to get step by index.

so to loop through the steps you can do like this

```
def tcase = context.getTestCase()
def stepCount = tcase.getTestStepCount()
for(int stepId = 0; stepId<stepCount; stepId++) {
    def tstep = tcase.getTestStepAt(stepId)
    if( tstep instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep ) {
        //only if this wsdl test do something:
        log.info( "label    : ${ tstep.getLabel() } " )
        log.info( "   class : ${ tstep.getClass() } " )
        log.info( "   props : ${ tstep.getPropertyNames() } " )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daggett, this is great; how would I implement the XML part. Thank you !